# Jenkins start applicaitonService on slave using ant and bat file

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, ant

I am using master/slave Jenkins. Now, i have a Jenkins Slave machine on Windows. On slave machine I have an ANT file that invoked a .bat file using

```
<exec executable = "<some-location>\applicationService.bat" > <arg value = "start"> </exec>
```

Using Jenkins Job I am invoking this ANT file. This ANT file runs Successfully(shown on Jenkins console logs) but the service is not started. I did check the task-Manager and logs. This applicationService.bat starts a Java Spring service. When I manually run this ANT on slave machine it works as expected.

Please suggest.

created Slave using these steps : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows

Answer (score 0):

> When I manually run this ANT on slave machine it works as expected.

The fact that you can do it manually says that your case is a  permissions issue

- Make sure that you connecting slave as administrator and user that runs jenkins jobs on slave has permissions to start Java Spring service.

Comment: I do not think it is a permission issue. Jenkins was able to run the ANT script. As it did executed tasks in the ANT file like unzip artifacts etc.Only the task to run .bat file was shown in the Ant logs as successful but no service was started in slave machine.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, `bat` files need to be executed from `cmd` with the `/c` switch, rather than directly as their own executables.

```
<exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c" />
    <arg value="path/to/file/location/applicationService.bat" />
    <arg value="start" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. The service was started. However I am not able to see the command prompt window open up on the slave machine. Any reason why it is so ?